# remove rows with duplicate attribute from json data

Tags: jquery, .net, visual-studio-2010

I am a bit New Here ..I am trying to Learn Jquery ..
In Jquery .I want only those rows which have unique Title ..(i.e.) rows  1,2 and 3 only ...

I have table structure like this :

In sql server I have table column like this

```
QuestionType    Title
Parent1        A
Parent2        B
Child1         X
Child1         X
Child1         X
```

this is my ajax function

```
$.ajax({
    //parameters
    success: function (response) {
        result= response.d;

        if (result.QuestionType == "Child1") {

            //remove duplicate question.Title

        //I tried Code like this : if(!$.unique(question.Title))
                      //{$.Remove()}
                      //this is not working

        }
```

I also Tried this Code:

```
                var groups = [];
                $.each(chick, function (i, item) {
                    $.each(item.Title, function (j, group) {
                        if ($.inArray(group, groups) == -1) {
                            groups.push(group);
                        }
                    });
                });
```

This is also not working
I have seen similar post which are using remove() and unique()..But I am not getting it right way ..  I am also looking if there is some lambda expression can be used in JQuery like distinct() function..But not getting it right way ...

Any suggestion would be Helpful

Comment: If possible try to implement on server side to return distinct data instead of returning large chunk of data and deleting in client side.

Comment: I m not allowed for it..i need to remove at json data

Comment: ok, so 'result' will be array of object with 'QuestionType' and 'Title' properties?

Comment: yes..with unique titles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$.ajax({
    //parameters
    success: function (response) {
        result= response.d;

var d= {};
 //array with unique objects
var u= [];

$.each(result, function(i, el) {

    if (!d[el.Title]) {
        d[el.Title] = true;
        u.push(el);
    }
});
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To work on the DOM-tree, first the subject must be inserted into the DOM, i.e. in a `<template>` tag which won't be rendered. Then this would work on your example table if `<table id="filter-table">`:

```
var items = [];

$('#filter-table tr td:nth-child(2)').filter(function(i, item)
{
    var exists = -1 !== items.indexOf(item.textContent);
    items.push(item.textContent);
    return exists;
}).parent().remove();
```

Running example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GT5cV/) (with hardcoded DOM)

Comment: actually it is the table in sql ..Not in HTML ..Apology from my side for not clearing earlier ..I have Edited my post